# Cant set cookie using nestjs(fastify) for nextjs frontend using Set-cookie header

Tags: node.js, next.js, nestjs, next.js13, next.js14

Solved. In axios config missed withCredentials prop.
I'm building website using Nestjs(fastify) for api: localhost:3001 and Nextjs 14.0.3 for frontend: localhost:3000.

I'm trying to set cookie but it doesnt work. The set-cookie seems to be correct but cookie doesn't appear in application/cookie tab in chrome dev tools. No console errors or warnings appear in chrome. In insomnia API client cookie works.

My response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
vary: Origin
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
access-control-allow-credentials: true
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
set-cookie: token=ced93884671e13aa95e9368f; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 26 Nov 2033 13:10:59 GMT; HttpOnly
content-length: 203
Date: Wed, 29 Nov 2023 13:10:59 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=72
```

And my request headers

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 49
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:3001
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set cookie with server action in Next.js AppRoute.

```
'use server';

import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export const setCookie = async (name: string, value: string) => {
  cookies().set(name, value);
};
```